# android SimpleCursorAdapter populate ListView from Database

Tags: listview, simplecursoradapter

I am trying to populate ListView from database through SimpleCursorAdapter but it gives error. 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist

here is my BlistActivity that contain my ListView.

```
    public class BListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_blist);

    MyDBHandler myDBHandler = new MyDBHandler(this,null,3);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.blistView);
    Cursor cursor = myDBHandler.showAllRecords();
    String[] columnNames = new String[]{"name_number"};
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            cursor,
            columnNames,
            new int[]{android.R.id.text1});
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

here is my xml code for this activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.haroon.vuultimateblocker.BListActivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/blistView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

it is also worth mentioning that i need the listView as multiplechoice.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? Do you just want to list out the data, if so do this

private ListView lvCities;
    private static String[]cities={"London","Paris","NewYork" };

put that above onCreate,
in onCreate start this method initListView();

and then make that method below onCreate, like this

private void initListView() {
        lvCities=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvCities);

```
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>adapter=new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked,cities);

    lvCities.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Modify the xml file to have a listView with this id

android:id="@+id/lvCities"

If you need to use a database helper, I think you need another class where you implement SQLite to write your data to a table which you can then modify but that's a whole other set of code which you can find on stackOverflow or other sites, there are many ways of implementing it depending on what you need.

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist

This error means that you didn't provided the column "_id" in the cursor, it is android convention to use _id column with the cursor when using it for adapters. An Example of a working cursor:

```
String tableName = "mTable";
String columns[] = {"_id", "column1", "column2", "column3"};
cursor = db.query(table, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
```

In your case, edit the showAllRecords() method of MyDBHandler class where you return the Cursor:

```
Cursor cursor = myDBHandler.showAllRecords();
```

You can either update the table to include _id column or you can get it this way using the Alias and **ROWID**:

```
SELECT myTable.ROWID AS _id, column1, column2, column3... from myTable
```